# Limit order type to avoid errors when completing an order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, types, orders

I want to display a report based on the order status if it's completed then display some data

but it works with all order status for example if i put on-hold it gets the data but when I put completed I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method WC_Order_Refund::get_order_number()

here is my code

```
    //Get Report for Orders that have status of delivered
foreach( $orders as $order ){
    if ( $order->get_status() === 'completed'){
        $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_name = $item->get_name();
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        }
        $orders_completed .=  '<tr><td>' . $order->get_order_number() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_date_created()->date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_status() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_total() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $product_id . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $product_name . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_item_count() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_billing_email() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_billing_phone() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method_title'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

if i changed 'completed' to 'on-hold' or any other status it will work and get the data

but how to make it work with completed orders?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to the **order type** that should be "shop order"… There is 2 ways:

1) Check the **order type**, which **need to be "shop_order"** *(but not "shop_order_refund")*. So you can use the method get_type() that also works for `WC_Order_Refund` class like:

```
foreach( $orders as $order ){
    if ( $order->get_type() === 'shop_order' && $order->get_status() === 'completed'){
        $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_name = $item->get_name();
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        }
        $orders_completed .=  '<tr><td>' . $order->get_order_number() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_date_created()->date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_status() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_total() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $product_id . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $product_name . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_item_count() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_billing_email() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_billing_phone() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method_title'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
};
```

2) change the WC_Order_Query, targeting only "shop_order" post type:

```
$orders = wc_get_orders( array('limit' => -1, 'type' => 'shop_order') );
```

**Both ways will avoid to get this fatal error**

Comment: As Always Best Answer.
Problem Solved Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 1):

For get order list satuts completed you can use this

```
if ($order->payment_complete()){

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i still get 
> error: Call to undefined method WC_Order_Refund::payment_complete()

Comment: your WooCommerce version ?

Comment: Latest version dfd

Comment: you are using this $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); to get order list ?

Comment: im using  `$orders = wc_get_orders( array('numberposts' => -1) );` to get all orders